# Golang interface conversion error when trying to iterate through map of json array

Tags: json, loops, go

I'm having an issue when I'm try to iterate through a map of some json.

The original JSON data looks like this:

```
"dataArray": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "url": "/some/url"
    },
    {
      "name": "second",
      "url": "/another/url"
    }
]
```

the map looks like this:

```
[map[name:default url:/some/url] map[name:second url:/another/url]]
```

The code looks like this:

```
for _, urlItem := range item.(map[string]interface{}){
   do some stuff
}
```

This normally works when it's a JSON object, but this is an array in the JSON and I get the following error:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not just tag some structs and Unmarshal the JSON the sane way?

Comment: I would, but sometimes the data is there and other times it isn't so I need to test the data before it goes in. It's a pain, but if there is no data to go in an array then the field that holds the array doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean the field in the JSON doesn't exist? You can just check for nil in that case.

Comment: Try this https://play.golang.org/p/Y79-0eWJyg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is :

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not
>   map[string]interface {}

in your code you're converting `item` into `map[string]interface{}` :

```
for _, urlItem := range item.(map[string]interface{}){
   do some stuff
}
```

But the actual `item` is `[]interface {}` : change your covert type to this.

Because as you can see your result data is :

```
[map[name:default url:/some/url] map[name:second url:/another/url]]
```

it is an `array` that has `map`. not `map`.

First you can convert your data to `[]interface{}` and then get the index of that and convert it to `map[string]interface{}`.
so an example will look like this :

```
data := item.([]interface{})
for _,value := range data{
  yourMap := value.(map[string]interface{})
  //name value
  name := yourMap["name"].(string) // and so on
}
```